# How to make an XML header with given attributes in LINQ-to-XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am in need to reproduce the following XML header using LINQ to XML and C#:

```
<ns0:Subject_Sample xmlns:ns0="fhrb"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="fhrb file:FHRB_NEW_SUBJECT_SAMPLE.xsd" >
```

First problem is that when I adapt .NET help example, things start disappear from my header. For example:

```
XElement myTree = new XElement(ns0 + "Subject_Sample",
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ns0", "http://www.adventure-works.com" )         
        );
```

gives sort of what I need

```
 <ns0:Subject_Sample xmlns:ns0="http://www.adventure-works.com">
```

but if I change XAttribute parameter from web URL to string (eg "fhrb") then for some reason "ns0:" disappears from the tag (ns0:Subject_Sample becomes just Subject_Sample).

Then, I decided to try to make schemaLocation attribute by the following code:

```
XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
XNamespace ns0 = "http://www.adventure-works.com";
XElement myTree = new XElement(ns0 + "Subject_Sample",
new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ns0", "http://www.adventure-works.com" ),
            new XAttribute(xsi+"schemaLocation", "fhrb file:/fhrb.xsd"));
```

but the result i got was as follows, strange p1 appeared.

```
 <ns0:Subject_Sample xmlns:ns0="http://www.adventure-works.com" p1:schemaLocation="fhrb file:/fhrb.xsd" xmlns:p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Question is: how I can reproduce the needed format of header by means of LINQ to XML? And what is the logic behind the appearance/disappearance/naming of these attributes??

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
XNamespace ns0 = "fhrb";
XElement myTree = new XElement(ns0 + "Subject_Sample",
                                  new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi),
                                  new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ns0", ns0),
                                  new XAttribute(xsi + "schemaLocation", "fhrb file:FHRB_NEW_SUBJECT_SAMPLE.xsd")
                              );
```